# R: Change multiline character to single-document corpus

Tags: r, tm, documents, corpus

I'm reading in a file of tweets. Each tweet is on its own line. When I use readLines(), the result is a character with thousands of lines.

Using the tm package gives me a VCorpus object with thousands of documents, and the resulting TermDocumentMatrix is enormous garbage.

Here's an example:

```
x <- c("hello my name is bill","my favorite food is eating")
c <- Corpus(VectorSource(x))
inspect(c)
```

I could loop through the lines and paste them together, but that seems highly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found:

```
x <- c("hello my name is bill","my favorite food is eating")
c <- Corpus(VectorSource(concat(x,collapse=" ")))
inspect(c)
```

Doesn't seem terribly efficient either, compared with reading in the tweets as a single line in the first place.